# Наложение одного изображения на другое при прокрутке

Tags: javascript, css, вёрстка, прокрутка

1. Я хочу использовать наложение изображений, когда страница прокручивается, как [здесь](http://www.heatofthemoment.org/features/droughtmigrants/) (посмотрите, как появляются капли дождя и рыбы, а человек исчезает при прокрутке).
2. Я [попытался](http://output.jsbin.com/lasomig/10) сделать это с эффектом параллакса, используя только CSS, но это не то, что мне нужно потому, что параллакс не работает на мобильных устройствах, как в примере выше.

Буду благодарен, если посоветуете мне какие-нибудь решения для JavaScript с `onscroll` или что-то еще.

**Мой код:**

HTML

```
<body>
<div class="parallax">
    <div class="bg_one"></div>
    <div class="bg_two"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.parallax [class*="bg_"] {
 position: relative;
 height: 900px;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-position: center;
 background-size: cover;
}

.parallax .bg_one {
 background-image: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AYNesterov/data_sets/master/внутри%20пни.png);
}
.parallax .bg_two {
 background-image: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AYNesterov/data_sets/master/внутри%20квартиры.png);
}
```

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/52150482/7394871

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Один довольно простенький пример накладывания при прокрутке страницы блоков друг на друга, меняя их уровень прозрачности для элементов с помощью свойства `opacity`.

В двух вариантах, но оба еще в сыром виде и необходимо их дорабатывать.

Вариант 1:

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  var scrollCoef = 0.00008;
  $.when(
    $('.part1').animate({
      opacity: $(window).scrollTop() * scrollCoef
    }, 5).promise()
  ).done(function() {
    $('.part2').animate({
        opacity: $(window).scrollTop() * scrollCoef
      }, 10).promise()
      .done(function() {
        $('.part3').animate({
            opacity: $(window).scrollTop() * scrollCoef
          }, 10).promise()
          .done(function() {
            $('.part4').animate({
                opacity: $(window).scrollTop() * scrollCoef
              }, 10).promise()
              .done(function() {
                $('.part5').animate({
                  opacity: $(window).scrollTop() * scrollCoef
                }, 10).promise().done(function() {
                  $('.part6').animate({
                    opacity: $(window).scrollTop() * scrollCoef
                  }, 10).promise()
                })
              })
          })
      })
  })
});

$(function() {
  var topPos = $('.name').offset().top;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var top = $(document).scrollTop(),
      pip = $('.parallax').offset().top,
      height = $('.name').outerHeight();
    if (top > topPos && top < pip - height) {
      $('.name').addClass('name__fixed').removeAttr("style");
    } else if (top > pip - height) {
      $('.name').removeClass('name__fixed').css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'bottom': '0'
      });
    } else {
      $('.name').removeClass('name__fixed');
    }
  });
});

//$(window).on('scroll', function() {
//  var scrollCoef = 0.00006;
//  $('.part2').animate({
//    opacity: $(window).scrollTop() * scrollCoef
//  }, 10);
//});
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.cover {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  z-index: 7;
}

.name {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 8;
  transition: all 2s;
}

.name__fixed {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 7;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition: all 2s;
}

h1,
h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  padding-top: 20%;
}

h2 {
  padding: 0 50px;
}

.footer h2 {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

p {
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px 50px;
  line-height: 1.3;
}

img {
  width: 130px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.footer {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  z-index: 7;
}

.copyright {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  color: brown;
}

.parallax {
  position: relative;
  height: 1600px;
  z-index: 6;
}

.part [class*="part"] {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: right bottom;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0;
}

.part1 {
  opacity: 1!important;
  z-index: 1;
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/hfqMu7P.jpg);
}

.part2 {
  z-index: 2;
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/6jhppgB.jpg);
}

.part3 {
  z-index: 3;
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/Eybhb0n.jpg);
}

.part4 {
  z-index: 4;
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/HaBqbXH.jpg);
}

.part5 {
  z-index: 5;
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/w3f15YP.jpg);
}

.part6 {
  z-index: 6;
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/tWd7qSn.jpg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cover">
  <div class="name">
    <h1>Иван Константинович Айвазовский</h1>
    <h2>Русский художник</h2>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parallax">
  <div class="part">
    <div class="part1"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parallax">
  <div class="part">
    <div class="part2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parallax">
  <div class="part">
    <div class="part3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parallax">
  <div class="part">
    <div class="part4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parallax">
  <div class="part">
    <div class="part5"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parallax">
  <div class="part">
    <div class="part6"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <h2>Иван Константинович<br>Айвазовский</h2>
  <p>Русский художник-маринист, баталист, коллекционер, меценат. Живописец Главного Морского штаба, академик и почётный член Императорской Академии художеств, почётный член Академий художеств в Амстердаме, Риме, Париже, Флоренции и Штутгарте.</p>
  <p>С раннего детства, родившийся в Крыму Айвазовский, влюблялся в море, проводя долгое время на его берегах. Он длительное время сидел на берегу Черного моря и всматривался в каждую деталь и любовался красотой морского пейзажа. Возможно, именно это в сочетании
    необычайного таланта, сделало его популярным в своем деле художником маринистом, чем известен Иван Айвазовский. За все время своего творчества он написал около 1000 картин. На всех в основном изображено море.</p>
  <p>Айвазовский Иван Константинович − один из мировых выдающихся художников маринистов. Картины этого гениального живописца во все времена покоряют души ценителей искусства. Его творчество отличительно от других художников подобного стиля писания картин,
    что принесло ему необыкновенную мировую популярность.</p>
  <p><img src="https://i.imgur.com/Xfpr18s.png">
    <p>
      <div class="copyright">©ЖУРНАЛКРЫМ.РФ</div>
</div>
```

Вариант 2:

```js
$(function() {
  var wnd = $(window),
    opacityControl = $('.part2');
  wnd.scroll(function() {
    var top = wnd.scrollTop(),
      opacity = top > 10000 ? 1 : top * 2 / 10000;
    opacityControl.css('opacity', opacity);
  });
});
$(function() {
  var wnd = $(window),
    opacityControl = $('.part3');
  wnd.scroll(function() {
    var top = wnd.scrollTop(),
      opacity = top > 20000 ? 1 : top * 2 / 20000;
    opacityControl.css('opacity', opacity);
  });
});
$(function() {
  var wnd = $(window),
    opacityControl = $('.part4');
  wnd.scroll(function() {
    var top = wnd.scrollTop(),
      opacity = top > 30000 ? 1 : top * 2 / 30000;
    opacityControl.css('opacity', opacity);
  });
});
$(function() {
  var wnd = $(window),
    opacityControl = $('.part5');
  wnd.scroll(function() {
    var top = wnd.scrollTop(),
      opacity = top > 60000 ? 1 : top * 2 / 60000;
    opacityControl.css('opacity', opacity);
  });
});
$(function() {
  var wnd = $(window),
    opacityControl = $('.part6');
  wnd.scroll(function() {
    var top = wnd.scrollTop(),
      opacity = top > 60000 ? 1 : top * 2 / 60000;
    opacityControl.css('opacity', opacity);
  });
});


$(function() {
  var topPos = $('.name').offset().top;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var top = $(document).scrollTop(),
      pip = $('.parallax').offset().top,
      height = $('.name').outerHeight();
    if (top > topPos && top < pip - height) {
      $('.name').addClass('name__fixed').removeAttr("style");
    } else if (top > pip - height) {
      $('.name').removeClass('name__fixed').css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'bottom': '0'
      });
    } else {
      $('.name').removeClass('name__fixed');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.cover {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  z-index: 7;
}

.name {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 8;
  transition: all 2s;
}

.name__fixed {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 7;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition: all 2s;
}

h1,
h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  padding-top: 20%;
}

h2 {
  padding: 0 50px;
}

.footer h2 {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

p {
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px 50px;
  line-height: 1.3;
}

img {
  width: 130px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.footer {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  z-index: 7;
}

.copyright {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  color: gray;
}

.part1 {
  opacity: 1!important;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  height: 1500px;
}

.part2 {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  height: 1500px;
}

.part3 {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  position: relative;
  height: 1500px;
}

.part4 {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 4;
  position: relative;
  height: 1500px;
}

.part5 {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 5;
  position: relative;
  height: 1500px;
}

.part6 {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 6;
  position: relative;
  height: 3000px;
}

.part1:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/hfqMu7P.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: right bottom;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  visibility: visible;
  z-index: 1;
}

.part2:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/6jhppgB.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: right bottom;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  visibility: visible;
  z-index: 2;
}

.part3:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/Eybhb0n.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: right bottom;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  visibility: visible;
  z-index: 3;
}

.part4:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/HaBqbXH.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: right bottom;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  visibility: visible;
  z-index: 4;
}

.part5:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/w3f15YP.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: right bottom;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  visibility: visible;
  z-index: 5;
}

.part6:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/tWd7qSn.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: right bottom;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  visibility: visible;
  z-index: 6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cover">
  <div class="name">
    <h1>Иван Константинович Айвазовский</h1>
    <h2>Русский художник</h2>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parallax parallax__1">
  <div class="part part_01">
    <div class="part1"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parallax parallax__2">
  <div class="part part_02">
    <div class="part2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parallax parallax__3">
  <div class="part part_03">
    <div class="part3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parallax parallax__4">
  <div class="part part_04">
    <div class="part4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parallax parallax__5">
  <div class="part part_05">
    <div class="part5"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parallax parallax__6">
  <div class="part part_06">
    <div class="part6"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <h2>Иван Константинович<br>Айвазовский</h2>
  <p>Русский художник-маринист, баталист, коллекционер, меценат. Живописец Главного Морского штаба, академик и почётный член Императорской Академии художеств, почётный член Академий художеств в Амстердаме, Риме, Париже, Флоренции и Штутгарте.</p>
  <p>С раннего детства, родившийся в Крыму Айвазовский, влюблялся в море, проводя долгое время на его берегах. Он длительное время сидел на берегу Черного моря и всматривался в каждую деталь и любовался красотой морского пейзажа. Возможно, именно это в сочетании
    необычайного таланта, сделало его популярным в своем деле художником маринистом, чем известен Иван Айвазовский. За все время своего творчества он написал около 1000 картин. На всех в основном изображено море.</p>
  <p>Айвазовский Иван Константинович − один из мировых выдающихся художников маринистов. Картины этого гениального живописца во все времена покоряют души ценителей искусства. Его творчество отличительно от других художников подобного стиля писания картин,
    что принесло ему необыкновенную мировую популярность.</p>
  <p><img src="https://i.imgur.com/Xfpr18s.png">
    <p>
      <div class="copyright">©ЖУРНАЛКРЫМ.РФ</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Еще один пример накладывания при прокрутке страницы блоков друг на друга. А-ля параллакс. Логика такая же, как и приведена в вопросе.

И вопрос остается до сих пор открытым: на мобильных устройствах `fixed` не работает. Возможно, что необходимо какое-то решение на JavaScript.

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parallax [class*="bg_"] {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center bottom;
  background-size: cover;
}

.parallax .bg_zero {
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  text-shadow: -0 -1px 0 black, 0 -1px 0 black, -0 1px 0 black, 0 1px 0 black, -1px -0 0 black, 1px -0 0 black, -1px 0 0 black, 1px 0 0 black, -1px -1px 0 black, 1px -1px 0 black, -1px 1px 0 black, 1px 1px 0 black, -1px -1px 0 black, 1px -1px 0 black, -1px 1px 0 black, 1px 1px 0 black;
}

.parallax .bg_zero h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 15%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.parallax .bg_zero h2 {
  font-size: 15px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 30%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.parallax .bg_one {
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/xXynj4T.jpg);
}

.parallax .bg_two {
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/JNvsum3.jpg);
}

.parallax .bg_three {
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/YuJTogJ.jpg);
}

.parallax .bg_four {
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/kOQVARJ.jpg);
}

.parallax .bg_five {
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/b9yGop3.jpg);
}

.parallax .bg_six {
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/1yKBQr0.jpg);
}

.parallax .bg_seven {
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/MP2lRdb.jpg);
}

.parallax .bg_eight {
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/Gn6v7kD.jpg);
}

.parallax .bg_nine {
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/EXCfuZT.jpg);
}

.parallax .bg_ten {
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/p9oECii.jpg);
}

.parallax .bg_eleven {
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/y9sEXhA.jpg);
}

.parallax .bg_twelve {
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/EOF3ypJ.jpg);
  background-position: left bottom;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: 0 -30px 30px -30px gray;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.info {
  padding-left: 30%;
}

.info h2,
.info h3 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.info h2 {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 40px 10px 5px 0;
}

.info h3 {
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 5px 20px 5px 0;
}

.info p {
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 5px 40px 0 20%;
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-align: justify;
}

p.span {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.copyright {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 40px;
  right: 40px;
  font-size: 9px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

@keyframes arrow {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  70% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  73% {
    transform: translateY(7px);
  }
  76% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  79% {
    transform: translateY(7px);
  }
  82% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}

#arrow {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  animation: arrow 5s linear infinite;
}

#arrow .arrow {
  transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
}

#arrow:hover .arrow {
  top: 5px;
}

#arrow .arrow_down {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
}

#arrow .arrow_down {
  background: black;
}

#arrow .arrow_down:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: transparent;
}

#arrow .arrow_down:after {
  top: 0px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.turn_down {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 60px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-shadow: none;
  color: black;
}

.turn_down:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -60px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: white;
}

.parallax__none {
  display: none;
}

.parallax__none p {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .parallax {
    display: none;
  }
  .parallax__none {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parallax">
  <div class="bg_zero">
    <h1>Памятник затопленным кораблям</h1>
    <h2>в городе-герое Севастополе</h2>
    <div class="turn_down">Крутите вниз</div>
    <div id="arrow">
      <div class="arrow arrow_down"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bg_one"></div>
  <div class="bg_two"></div>
  <div class="bg_three"></div>
  <div class="bg_four"></div>
  <div class="bg_five"></div>
  <div class="bg_six"></div>
  <div class="bg_seven"></div>
  <div class="bg_eight"></div>
  <div class="bg_nine"></div>
  <div class="bg_ten"></div>
  <div class="bg_eleven"></div>
  <div class="bg_twelve">
    <div class="info">
      <h2>Памятник<br>затопленным кораблям</h2>
      <h3>в городе-герое Севастополе</h3>
      <p>Памятник затопленным кораблям – монумент в Севастопольской бухте в память парусным кораблям, затопленным в 1854-1855 годах для заграждения входа неприятельских судов на рейд. Памятник сооружен в 1905 году к 50-летию Первой обороны Севастополя, во
        время которой были затоплены русские парусные корабли, «чтобы заградить вход неприятельским судам на рейд и тем самым спасти Севастополь» (П.С.Нахимов).</p>
      <p>Изображение этого памятника по праву считается эмблемой города, его можно также увидеть и на современном гербе Севастополя. Рядом с памятником Затопленным кораблям всегда очень много народа. Каждый старается сделать фото на память на фоне памятника,
        однако мало кто знает его удивительную историю.</p>
      <p class="span">В 2020 году Памятнику Затопленным кораблям исполняется 115 лет!</p>
      <div class="copyright">Источник: журналкрым.рф</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parallax__none">
  <p>Откройте, пожалуйста, на всю страницу. Спасибо!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

> [Перевод ответа @enxaneta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52150971/7394871) на вопрос EnSO: [Image overlay when
>   scrolling (javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52150482/7394871)

Это очень хорошая идея!

Я тестировал ваш код не в реальном mobil, а на `Chrome > inspect> toggle device toolbar`(слева вверху). Это позволяет вам тестировать веб-страницу в мобильной среде. Я сделал несколько изменений в вашем CSS, и это похоже  работает:

```css
.parallax [class*="bg_"] {
 position: relative;
 height: 100vh;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-position: top center;
 background-size: cover;
}

.parallax .bg_one {
 background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/dG338.png);
}
.parallax .bg_two {
 background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQqNc.png);
}
```

```html
<div class="parallax">
    <div class="bg_one"></div>
    <div class="bg_two"></div>
</div>
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52150971/7394871): @enxaneta

Comment: @Sevastopol'  а если за скроллбар потянуть будет тормозить ??

Comment: @Sevastopol' у меня тупит только если калёсиком а если за скроллбар нормально