# background-attachment: fixed на мобильных устройствах. Эффект параллакса

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax, эффекты

Есть такой эффект а-ля параллакс, как накладывание при прокрутке страницы одного изображения на другое с помощью свойства `background-attachment: fixed;`.

*Подобная тема чуть ранее была озвучена в вопросе ["Наложение одного изображения на другое при прокрутке"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1070146/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B5), однако, к сожалению, своего продолжения не получила.*

Мы знаем, что такое свойство как **`background-attachment: fixed;` на мобильных устройствах не работает**. Насколько мне известно, есть плагины, которые абсолютным позиционированием частично решают эту задачу, но по некоторым причинам это не подходит. Хотелось бы знать, возможно ли какое-то компактное и качественное решение на JavaScript? Знаю, что на Stack Overflow есть высококлассные специалисты, которым вполне под силу решить такую задачу. Пожалуйста, не проходите мимо! Благодарю!

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parallax [class*="bg_"] {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.parallax .bg_01 {
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/83K6mAS.jpg);
}

.parallax .bg_02 {
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/MAdlfFV.jpg);
}

.parallax .bg_03 {
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/jd293yl.jpg);
}

.parallax .bg_04 {
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/yDfuOGe.jpg);
}

.parallax .bg_05 {
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/5F2KlXu.jpg);
}

.parallax .bg_06 {
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/KZMuHF5.jpg);
}

.parallax .bg_07 {
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/QGxf3XK.jpg);
}

.parallax .bg_08 {
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/g1MzlzE.jpg);
}

.parallax .bg_09 {
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/aY8eLSw.jpg);
}

.parallax .bg_10 {
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/McDqMkM.jpg);
}

.parallax .bg_11 {
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/BXgZ2qj.jpg);
}

.parallax .bg_12 {
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/aJoRigX.jpg);
}

.bg_00 {
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/V3ufAVQ.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div class="parallax">
  <div class="bg_01"></div>
  <div class="bg_02"></div>
  <div class="bg_03"></div>
  <div class="bg_04"></div>
  <div class="bg_05"></div>
  <div class="bg_06"></div>
  <div class="bg_07"></div>
  <div class="bg_08"></div>
  <div class="bg_09"></div>
  <div class="bg_10"></div>
  <div class="bg_11"></div>
  <div class="bg_12"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: может быть clippath поможет, но похоже что одним лишь css тут не обойдется

Comment: да, стоит учитывать, что телефоны в принципе работают с последними версиями -webkit-. Думаю, можно найти альтернативу, если понимать, что не нужна поддержка всяких там IE и других менее продвинутых версий браузера.

Comment: Может сложить это все в спрайт и двигать бэкграунд при свайпе?

Comment: Вам нужно именно сделать такой эффект с надписью или вас интересует эффект параллакса в общем случае?

Comment: @Sevastopol', нарвался на это вот: https://codepen.io/hexagoncircle/pen/povXoOo. Возможно можно будет использовать под текущие задачи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем предлогаю использовать jQuery

1) Сделана плавная прокрутка

2) Эффект паралакса для мобильных и ПК

> Внимание: добавлен элемент spacer для имитации контента

```js
$('.parallax').each(function() {
  var thisObj = $(this);
  var tH = $(this).outerHeight();
  var tY = $(this).position().top;
  var wH = $(window).height();
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var s = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (wH < tY) var offset = 1 - ((s + wH - tY) / (tY + tH));
    else var offset = 1 - (s / (tY + tH));
    thisObj.css('background-position', '0 ' + (offset * 100) + '%');
  });
});


(function($) {
  jQuery.scrollSpeed = function(step, speed, easing) {
    var $document = $(document),
      $window = $(window),
      $body = $('html, body'),
      option = easing || 'default',
      root = 0,
      scroll = false,
      scrollY,
      view;

    if (window.navigator.msPointerEnabled) return false;

    $window.on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
      if ($('.js-aDialogOpened').length == 0) {
        var deltaY = e.originalEvent.wheelDeltaY,
          detail = e.originalEvent.detail;
        scrollY = $document.height() > $window.height();
        scroll = true;

        if (scrollY) {
          view = $window.height();
          if (deltaY < 0 || detail > 0)
            root = (root + view) >= $document.height() ? root : root += step;
          if (deltaY > 0 || detail < 0)
            root = root <= 0 ? 0 : root -= step;
          $body.stop().animate({
            scrollTop: root
          }, speed, option, function() {
            scroll = false;
          });
        }

        return false;
      }

    }).on('scroll', function() {
      if (scrollY && !scroll) root = $window.scrollTop();
    }).on('resize', function() {
      if (scrollY && !scroll) view = $window.height();
    });
  };

  jQuery.easing.default = function(x, t, b, c, d) {
    return -c * ((t = t / d - 1) * t * t * t - 1) + b;
  };

})(jQuery);

$.scrollSpeed(100, 1000); // cкорость прокрутки
```

```css
.parallax {
  background: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/08/01/13/05/sea-2565253_1280.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-size: cover;
}

.spacer {
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="spacer"></div>

<div class="spacer"></div>

<div class="spacer"></div>

<div class="spacer"></div>

<div class="parallax" style="background-position: 0px 77.166%;">
  <h1>parallax effect</h1>
</div>

<div class="spacer"></div>

<div class="spacer"></div>

<div class="spacer"></div>

<div class="spacer"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```